# How do Jenkins multibranch pipelines work?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, multibranch-pipeline

We have a Jenkins server that contains multibranch pipeline jobs for around 20-30 repositories. Some of these repositories have around 30-40 branches although not all of these branches are being updated regularly but newer branches are being added.

This is my current understanding of how a multibranch pipeline works:

1. The pipe initially discovers the number of branches in the repository
2. It clones each branch separately on the first run
3. The pipeline for each branch will only be executed if poll scm command detects a change on that branch
4. If there is a change, the pipeline will only **pull** the changes and run the Jenkinsfile

Have I misunderstood anything?

The issue I am having mainly, is that the aforementioned Jenkins server was issued a warning by the Network team as it is eating up a lot of bandwidth (~140 GB in one day) and I was wondering how this is possible.

Comment: This is impossible to answer generally, it depends on your settings, build strategies, use of webhooks, periodic/nightly builds etc. You may get a better understanding if you look at your jobs and their history.

Comment: @MaratC thanks for the reply. I am unsure what you mean by build strategies but no there are no webhooks being used in any job. The jobs are set to poll the SCM every 15 seconds or so (this seems excessive but it was preset in this instance). Are you able to give any advice based on this "new" information? If not, can I know what kind of stuff to look for in the jobs and the job history? Thanks

Comment: You can start by counting all jobs that ran in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Will do. If the pipe basically just has the following stages: Checkout/Build/Unit Test/Code Analysis for each branch with each branch having a repository size of 1GB. And if the job has already been cloned into its workspace earlier, there is no need for it to clone each branch again, am I right?